# How to modify the Azure AD B2C SignIn/Signup page for Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an Azure web application that uses Azure AD B2C with Microsoft Identity user flow. The resulting page for SignIn and SignUp uses non-US English for the display prompts for Name and Last Name (the default apparently uses as display prompts Given Name and Surname). I need to find out if I can modify the standard display prompts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change any string AAD B2C renders by modifying the language: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-user-flow#customize-your-strings

Download the default English JSON for the page you’re interested in through the Azure portal, then modify the wording in the file. Then upload the json file back into the Azure portal.

Comment: Thanks! This was a big help.